# Python vertical lines in countour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, lines, contour

In a 2D plot, I normally use

`l, = pylab.plot([10, 10], [-1000,1000], color="g", lw=0.5)`
to plot vertical lines at x position 10 ranging from -1000 to 1000 in the vertical axes.

I would like to do the same in a contour plot 
how can I plot vertical lines in a contour plot?

In particular I am using this code bellow

```
# Blue-White-Red colorbar for plots with negative and positive values.
cdict = {'red':   ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
         'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
         'blue':  ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))}
my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap', cdict, 1024)

fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(3.46,2.14), frameon=False)
pylab.axes([0.17, 0.20, 0.50, 0.75])
p1 = pylab.imshow(
    dens.transpose()*10000.0,
    cmap=my_cmap, aspect='auto',
    interpolation='bicubic',
    vmin=-2.0, vmax=2.0,
    extent=(times[0],times[1],y[0]/1000.0,y[-1]/1000.0))
pylab.xlabel(r"$t\,[{\rm ps}]$")
pylab.ylabel(r"$y\,[\mu{\rm m}]$")
pylab.xlim([tmin,tmax])
#pylab.ylim(eRange)
ax2 = pylab.gcf().add_axes([0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0.75])
pylab.colorbar(mappable=p1,cax=ax2)
#pylab.axvline(x=5.0, color='k', linestyle='--')
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks([])
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
pylab.figtext(0.75, 0.10, r"$\times 10^{-4}$")
```

[contour plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHkDG.png)

How I plot a vertical line at t = 5 ?

the above commented line does not work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

The following code using `imshow` as well as `contour` works perfectly fine.
It uses the exact of plotting a line between two points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

z = np.random.rand(21,21)

fig, (ax, ax2)= plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(7,3))
ax.imshow(z, extent=[0,20,0,20], cmap="viridis")
ax.plot([5,5],[0,20], lw=10, c="r")

ax2.contour(z)
ax2.plot([5,5],[0,20], lw=10, c="r")

plt.show()
```

[image]